# Updating Multiple NCurses Windows

Tags: python, ncurses

I apologize in advance for a complicated question.

I am using NCurses with Python 3 to make a terminal dashboard. This dashboard has two parts: a logging section and a dictionary display section

[image]

The initialization code looks something like this:

```
panel = None
window = None
screen = None

def setup_terminal_logging():
    global panel
    global screen
    global window
    screen = curses.initscr()
    screen.nodelay(1)
    screen.border(0)

    maxy, maxx = screen.getmaxyx()

    height = 20
    # height, width, begin_y, begin_x
    window = curses.newwin(height, maxx-4, maxy-(height + 1), 2)

    panel = curses.newwin(25, maxx-4, 2, 2)
    panel.refresh()

    curses.setsyx(-1, -1)

    screen.refresh()
    window.refresh()
    window.scrollok(True)
    window.idlok(True)
    window.leaveok(True)

    terminal_handler = modules.log.CursesHandler(window)
    logger.addHandler(terminal_handler)
```

`CursesHandler` ties into logging and displays output to the console (bottom section of the screen). It looks something like this:

```
class CursesHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen

        curses.start_color()
        curses.use_default_colors()
        for i in range(0, curses.COLORS):
            curses.init_pair(i + 1, i, -1)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        screen = self.screen
        ufs = u'\n%s'
        screen.addstr(ufs % msg, 83)
        screen.refresh()
```

And the section at the top is updated by passing two dictionaries in a function and using the globally-scoped `window` and `panel` variables:

```
def update_terminal_display(data, values):
    global panel
    for k, j in enumerate([data, values]):
        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(j.items()):
            if "_locations" in key:
                continue
            logger.debug("-")
            panel.addstr(index + 2, 2 + (k * 50), str(key) + ": " + str(value))
        panel.refresh()
```

Everything seems to work great, although I've encountered some strange behavior.

If I remove the `logger.debug("-")` statement in the `update_terminal_display` method, the display prints out gibberish:

[image]

It's strange that literally only removing this statement can cause this behavior, especially when the top panel is separate from the bottom one.

Even more strange, I replaced `logger.debug("-")` with `window.refresh()` (which in effect is what it is calling), and it still doesn't work. How can I prevent this behavior from happening? What is causing them to conflict? Can I call a `refresh()` on one window without it interfering with another?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A complete program would help.  The screenshots seem to show that (at least some of) the escape characters are being dropped, as if something were reading the output of ncurses (to the screen) and adding *that* to the screen output.

Comment: Hello @JamesTaylor! Did You manage this? I'm also trying to make terminal dashboard, but have problem with handler.